# How to turn off Razer Synapse shortcuts on a keyboard?

Tags: razer-keyboard, razer-synapse

I have Razer Ornata Chroma and I'm using Razer Synapse to customize RGB on the keyboard. I noticed that I'm not able to use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> keyboard in one of the apps I'm using. When I exit the Synapse application, I'm able to use the shortcut successfully.

How can I disable Synapse from blocking me to use the shortcut?

I have Hypershift disabled, Gaming mode turned off, and no global shortcuts defined. OS: Windows 10.

Comment: I have the same problem, were you able to fix it?

Comment: @mortom123 take a look at the answer bellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its the module "Alexa" if you remove that it will be solved.
Goto

> Synapse -> Modules

and hover over the alexa module.
Then press the X in the top right corner.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone a similar problem and getting here from a search engine, my ALT + SHIFT + Q was not working in a game.

For me, the problem was Razer Cortex. Under FPS, there's an option for a keyboard shortcut to show/hide the FPS display and the keybind default is ALT + SHIFT + Q. Just changed it to some random keybind and everything is fine again.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar priblem with <kbd>altgr</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> not writing `{`,

The fix is that you have to go to `razer cortx` in the top right corner, click on the `cog` and then on `hotkeys` and there you can customise them.